# Handling null values in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

How to handle `null` values in Freemarker? I get some exceptions in the template when `null` values are present in data.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306732/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-freemarker-template

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use the `??` test operator:

This checks if the attribute of the object is not null:

```
<#if object.attribute??></#if>
```

This checks if object or attribute is not null:

```
<#if (object.attribute)??></#if>
```

Source: [FreeMarker Manual](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test)

Comment: What is the difference between this approach and has_content ??

Comment: `has_content`, next to null-checking, also checks if the value is not empty. This works for strings, sequences, hashes or collections. If the object is a date, boolean or a number, then it acts as non-empty. For all other types it will act as empty.

Comment: I have this problem where I have to check if the value in bean is null.I tried the following:${checknull(Bean.getValue())}, where checknull if a function <#function checknull x>
    <#if x??>
      <#return "">
    <#else>
      <#return x>
    </#if>
  </#function>   but I get "Error executing macro: checknull
required parameter: x is not specified." error

Comment: You have to reverse the returns: 
    <#function checknull x> 
        <#if x??> 
<#return x> <#else> <#return ""> </#if> </#function>

Comment: Please check below answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614219/3002336

Comment: @TomVerelst what if I want to check if both the object `and` attribute are not null?

Answer (score 138):

Starting from freemarker 2.3.7, you can use [this syntax](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing) :

```
${(object.attribute)!}
```

or, if you want display a default text when the attribute is `null` :

```
${(object.attribute)!"default text"}
```

Comment: For those who are using Freemarker as template engine for XDocReport, this is working after adding `<dependency><groupId>org.freemarker</groupId><artifactId>freemarker</artifactId><version>2.3.22</version></dependency>` to your pom.xml.

Comment: How do you do it if you have a date and the date could be null? In other words object.dateAcquired where dateAcquired could be null and you have ${object.dateAcquired?date}

Comment: @StephaneGrenier use `${(object.dateAcquired?date)!"not present"}`

Comment: Great example. Helped me alot. The bracket, however are obsolet.

`${salutation!'Dear Mr. or Mrs.'}`

Comment: Any idea how could I print .now?long on default value?

Answer (score 5):

I think it works the other way

```
<#if object.attribute??>
   Do whatever you want....
</#if>
```

If `object.attribute` is NOT NULL, then the content will be printed.

Comment: If `object` is nullable also then we can use `(object.attribute)??`

Answer (score 1):

Use **`??`** operator at the end of your `<#if>` statement.

This example demonstrates how to handle `null` values for two lists in a Freemaker template.

```
List of cars:
<#if cars??>
    <#list cars as car>${car.owner};</#list>
</#if>
List of motocycles:
<#if motocycles??>
    <#list motocycles as motocycle>${motocycle.owner};</#list>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add more context if you have issues and this is what I have tried.

```
<#if Recipient.account_type?has_content>
  … (executes if variable exists)
<#else>
  … (executes if variable does not exist)
</#if>
```

This is more like Javascript IF and ELSE concept where we want to check whether this value or another chaining through required logic.

[Freemarker webite](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_contains)

[Other reference:](https://support.messagegears.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057308532-Null-Values-in-FreeMarker)

Scenario: Customer has ID and name combined like **13242 Harish**, so where our stakeholder need the only name, so I have tried this **${record.entity?keep_after(" ")}** and it did work, however, it can only work when you have space, but when a customer doesn't have space and one name, I had to do some IF ELSE condition to check Null value.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
${(user.isSuperman!false)?c}
```

**It will work when "isSuperman" is null and when have boolean value**

What we want:

- For "null" we want to output 'false'
- For boolean value and want to output value ('true' or 'false')

What we know:

- boolean need to convert to string by using "?c" [see Built-ins for booleans](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html)
- but null we cannot convert to string and we need to use "!" [see Handling missing values](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing)

Comment: Here what happens if the `user` is null?

Comment: @bee I think it will be an exception and I suggest we need to use extra circle brackets as  `${((user.isSuperman)!false)?c}`. Just test to be sure.

Comment: Yes, that's what's worked. Thanks.