# How to solve issue with quotes when using Freemarker with ckEditor (or any html editor)?

Tags: java, html, templates, ckeditor, freemarker

For example I have the following in my template

```
${(object.attribute)!"default text"}
```

Sometimes quotes are required, as in the above case where [FreeMarker can deal with dates that are null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950424/39371) and so on.

The problem is that my html editor automatically converts the quotes into the html escape characters `&quot;`. I was going to try to look at the source for FMParse.java which is where the exception is thrown and add a special exception but it's not available in the FreeMarker source...

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue is appreciated. I understand why the html editor such as ckEditor is treating the quotes, but in those cases how can I handle them with FreeMarker? I want an html editor because it's really great for the user to be able to get a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Does it also escape `'`? You can use that instead of `"` if it doesn't. As of the source code, it's `FTL.jj`, which is not a java file. But maybe you should just pre-process the content before passing it to FreeMarker be-unescaping sections that are between `${` and `}` (and I suppose also between `[#` and `]`, and `[/#` and `]`, etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately single quotes are also converted as &#39;

Comment: In terms of pre-processing it beforehand I thought about this but how can I be sure that I'm converting the correct quotes. For example how do I know they aren't legit quotes. Which then brought me into being able to parse the template language. And what if they added quotes within the default text. It basically gets ugly pretty quickly :(

Comment: As you are (well, CKEditor is) escaping the FTL tags and interpolations, the result is not FTL, it's some new syntax. So I don't think that per-proccessing can be avoided. Such a pre-processor could be a generally useful contribution. (And there are more difficult problems with WSYSWYG... like if you want to `#list` `<tr>...</tr>`-s, there's no visual place that corresponds to the source locations that are around those `tr` tags.)

Comment: I'm just starting to work with FreeMarker so I haven't even had the chance to try out the lists yet. I'll have to see what you mean when I get there before I can say anything informative on the subject, nevermind trying to implement a pre-processor.

Comment: There are some reporting tools and such that use FTL for ODF templates which are edited with OpenOffice etc. They face the same issues, so maybe there's already a solution in some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting

```
config.entities = false;
```

in the CKEditor configuration.

See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities