# Handling null values whilst printing a list with Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to build an HTML table from a collection of `Iterable<Object>` instances.

```
final Iterable<Iterable<Object>> rows = Lists.newArrayList(
    Lists.newArrayList( 1, "Fizz"),
    Lists.newArrayList( 2, "Buzz"),
    Lists.newArrayList( 3, null ));
```

This is added to my model with a key of "rows".

In my template file, I have the following markup:

```
<#list rows as row>
  <tr>
    <#list row as value>
      <td>${value!}</td>
    </#list>
  </tr>
</#list>
```

When I try to print out these values, the template falls over handling the `null` value of the final row:

> freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: The FreeMarker value exists, but has nothing inside it; the TemplateModel object (class: freemarker.ext.beans.StringModel) has returned a null instead of a String. This is possibly a bug in the non-FreeMarker code that builds the data-model.

```
The blamed expression:
==> value!
```

I have tried replacing `${value!}` with `${value?has_content}` and tried a few other combinations `<#if value??>` around the block, but I keep getting the same error.

How can I make my Freemarker template accept these `null` values and produce an empty string?

Comment: Look here is the answer:
[Handling null values in Freemarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950289/handling-null-values-in-freemarker)

Comment: As the error message suggests, it has to be figured out where do those `StringModel`-s with a `null` inside come from. The template language can't handle this because it's should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `value` object returns null form it's toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
${value!""}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can use the ?? test operator:
>
> This checks if the attribute of the object is not null:
>
> <#if object.attribute??>
>
> This checks if object or attribute is not null:
>
> <#if (object.attribute)??>
>
> Source: FreeMarker Manual

Look here is the answer:
[Handling null values in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950289/handling-null-values-in-freemarker)

Comment: I mentioned using `<#if value??>` around the expression not producing a different result. This does not work in this scenario.

Comment: <#if object.attribute??> <td>${value!}</td></#if>

Comment: @ACV best solution,  just add bracket both side (object.attribute)?? it will not fail if object is null.