# Best way to use multiple sequences for table columns in FreeMarker

Tags: java, html, layout, freemarker

I have two separate lists (sets) of data which i would like to use to create a table

```
ColumnA      ColumnB
Value1       Value1
Value2       Value2
Value3       Value3
Value4       Value4
             Value5
             Value6
```

I know i could do it by POJO where my sets will be POJO (e.g. a and b) fields and i can call them in template like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>ColumnA</th>
<th>ColumnB</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<#list object as c>
<td>${c.a}</td>
<td>${c.b}</td>
</#list>
</tr>
</table>
```

However I would like to use separate sets and populate ColumnA and ColumnsB separately

Would you please advise the best way to do it?

For instance:

data.put("set1", SET1)

data.put("set2", SET2)

template:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>ColumnA</th>
<th>ColumnB</th>
</tr>
<#list set1 as c>
<tr><td>${c}</td></tr>
</#list>
<#list set2 as d>
<tr><td>${d}</td></tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

So it will merge two sets for ColumnA

Comment: Please don't post answers in questions. Instead add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_sequence

> ### Retrieving data from a sequence
>
> This is the same as for hashes, but you can use the square bracket syntax only, and the expression in the brackets must evaluate to a number, not a string. For example to get the name of the first animal of the example data-model (remember that the number of the first item is 0, not 1): `animals[0].name`

and the sequence built-in `size`: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_size

> ### size
>
> The number of sub variables in sequence (as a numerical value). The highest possible index in sequence `s` is `s?size - 1` (since the index of the first subvariable is 0) assuming that the sequence has at least one subvariable.

If you want to find the largest size, use https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_min_max

> ### min, max
>
> Returns the smaller (`min`) or greatest (`max`) item of the sequence (or collection). The items must be either all numbers, or all date/time values of the same kind (date-only, time-only, date-time), or else a comparison error will occur

This allows you to do something like:

```
<#list 0..<[sequenceA?size, sequenceB?size]?max as i>
  <tr>
  <td>${sequenceA[i]!""}</td>
  <td>${sequenceB[i]!""}</td>
  </tr>
</#list>
```

See also:

- [Handling null values in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950289/handling-null-values-in-freemarker)

Comment: Hi Jasper. Iterating trough any sequence is not a problem for me, but how to populate ColumnA and ColumnB separately taking into account that the size of seqA/seqB may vary. So i may have ColumnA with 10 values size and ColumnB (based on seqB) has diff size

Comment: Then find the largest sequence size, use that and check for empty values in the `<#list>`. See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_min_max

Comment: Thanks Jasper, i managed to get two Columns populated properly

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it instead of thanking me in a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers