# advance pdf tempelate delete null or 0

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I create an Advanced PDF/HTML Template with the following script

```
<#list item.data_item as line>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="1"><span style="font-size:8px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">${line.item}</span></span></td>
    <td style="width: 3px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.rateCtnDev} / ${line.ratePcsDev}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.bonusBOnCtn} / ${line.bonusBOnPcs}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.price?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon1}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon2}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon3?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon4}</span></span></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon5}</span></span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.subTotNew?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.sisaCtnMod} / ${line.sisaPcsMod} </span></span></td>
    <td style="width: 39px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 41px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

after that a result like this will appear
[image]

there is 1 row which is an empty item (null) when typing <#if line.subTotNew != 0>  then, the result will delete the line item. how to delete only 1 empty row line (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's updated code in your script to delete only 1 empty row ilne (null): -

```
<#list item.data_item as line>
  <#if line.item?has_content> <!-- Check if item is not null or empty -->
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="1"><span style="font-size:8px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">${line.item}</span></span></td>
      <td style="width: 3px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.rateCtnDev} / ${line.ratePcsDev}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.bonusBOnCtn} / ${line.bonusBOnPcs}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.price?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon1}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon2}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon3?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon4}</span></span></td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.diskon5}</span></span></td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="1"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.subTotNew?number?string[",###"]}</span></span></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:9px;">${line.sisaCtnMod} / ${line.sisaPcsMod} </span></span></td>
      <td style="width: 39px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 41px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: sorry, but after I tried, it still doesn't work

Comment: Just reading up on the "has_content" operation: "works for strings, sequences, hashes or collections. If the object is a date, boolean or a number, then it acts as non-empty. For all other types it will act as empty." - Here's the link for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950289/handling-null-values-in-freemarker

Comment: As per the above link: 

You can use the ?? test operator:

This checks if the attribute of the object is not null:

<#if object.attribute??></#if>
This checks if object or attribute is not null:

<#if (object.attribute)??></#if>