# Error Sending FreeMarker Mail Encountered "{"

Tags: freemarker

password is coming from my Servlet into html file using free marker:

I want to check if ${password} coming from Servlet is null. I have tried:

Try 1:

```
 <#if password?has_content>
 <strong> Your password: </strong>${password}<br />
 </#if>
```

Try 2:

<#if password??>
  **Your password:** ${password}

Do I have to assign password before actually evaluating it?

Also tried:

Try 3:

```
 <#if ${password} != null>
 <strong> Your password: </strong>${password}<br />
 </#if>
```

Already checked here: [How to check if a variable exists in a FreeMarker template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306732/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-freemarker-template)

But not sure how to get ${password} evaluated?

I am this getting error for try 3 and almost similar errors for other options as well:

Error Sending FreeMarker Mail Encountered "{" at line 44, column 16 in *******.html.
Was expecting one of:
    ">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
     ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "!=" ...
    "=" ...
    "==" ...
    ">=" ...
     ...
    ">" ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
    ".." ...
     ...
     ...

Thank you.

This error is coming while I am doing:

Template tpl = cfg.getTemplate(template.getName());

Comment: "Almost similar"?! It'd make sense to actually provide those errors as well, since they'd be very different from try #3 which isn't legal syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I ll study more about the Markup in meanwhile .. I have no other detailed information than - it is not able to recognize the variable password - which I have passed in. When I pass password as: <strong> Your password: </strong>${password}<br /> - it is working fine - getting the password. However, using ${password} to check for NULL is throwing error at '{'. Thanks again.

Comment: Check what error messages are you getting in the first two cases, because they look good. The 3rd case is syntactically wrong (don't use `${}` inside FreeMarker tags).

Comment: use `<#if password != null>` instead of `<#if ${password} != null>`