# In XDocReport, how to handle null value?

Tags: xdocreport

Is there a way to handle null value for a  field in XDocReport? or do I need to manipulate it on my own? example:

```
if (thisVar == null)
  context.put("sampleText", "");
else
  context.put("sampleText", thisVar);
```

or is there an option in docx quick parts?

I found this line in the error message of XDocReport. However I could not understand where to apply this, in the template or in the code.

> Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to
>   something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default
>   value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use [#if
>   myOptionalVar??]when-present[#else]when-missing[/#if]. (These only
>   cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression,
>   use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docx, append `?if_exists` to the field name

> «${tx.amount?if_exists}»

you may also append `!`

> «${tx.amount!}»

Please refer to this link for those who uses freemarker. [How to check if a variable exists in a FreeMarker template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306732/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-freemarker-template)