# Freemarker If condition is NULL

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, freemarker

I only want a list with schools without an end date. In SQL I use always the condtion `is null`, how does it work in Freemarker?

```
<#list mergevelden.adres_instantie_344.betrokken_instanties.betrokken_instantie as scholen><br>
***<#if scholen.tm="null">***
${scholen.instantie.volledige_naam}
${scholen.instantie.adressen.adres.straat} ${scholen.instantie.adressen.adres.huisnummer}
${scholen.instantie.adressen.adres.postcode}  ${scholen.instantie.adressen.adres.woonplaats?upper_case}<br>
</#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable exists in a FreeMarker template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306732/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-freemarker-template)

Answer (score 1):

`scholen.tm??` tells if `scholen.tm` exists (not `null`). So that's the opposite of what you are asking, but you can invert it as `!scholen.tm??`. But it's nicer to use the `#if` branch for the case where `scholen.tm` exists, then the `#else` branch for when it doesn't.

Also note that in many cases you can avoid the `#if`. Like if you just want a default value, then you can do something like `foo.bar!'The default if bar is null'`.